# Sagepay upgrade from 2.33 to 3.00 AES & response form

Tags: php, encryption, aes, opayo

I'm a junior dev (new on the job) being tasked with carrying out an upgrade from Sagepay 2.23 --> 3.00. (on a site we've recently taken over) I've made the change to VPSProtocol and I think i've successfully implemented a move to AES.

However, the previous chunk of code was set to:

```
$strCrypt = base64Encode(SimpleXor($strPost,$strEncryptionPassword));
```

I intend to comment that out and have popped this in:

```
function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize)
{
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    //echo "<br/>Padding:".str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad)."<";
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encryptFieldData($input)
{
    $key = $strEncryptionPassword;
    $iv = $key;

    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "", MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "");
    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher,$input );
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);

        $enc = bin2hex($cipherText);
    }
    return $enc;
}

$datapadded = pkcs5_pad($str,16);
$cryptpadded = "@" . encryptFieldData($datapadded);
```

And made the change here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<? echo $cryptpadded ?>">
```

I think that's enough, i'm awaiting access to the Sagepay test environment.

In terms of the Response Field, I don't fully understand where to implement the required changes. The sample code provided lists this information, but the existing php file does not appear to include any data for a response field.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what is being sent as Success/Failure URLs with the transaction post, and then work back to the code from there. You'll basically need to decrypt the crypt string that Sage Pay return, which contains the transaction outcome / transactionIDs and  (remember to remove the '@' before trying to decrypt).